I am trying to remove a certain index value for ran_word but I cant figure it out
I tried using functions like pop or remove but I cant remove a specific index by using the index of another list you can see what I was trying to do on the second to last section. please help I have been looking for an answer all day I don't know what to do.
import random

print("welcome to hang man you have 5 guesses to get the word right good luck:")

words = "stage thought bath noxious zip crown unwritten quickest promise soft vague unruly fine weak film room pig passenger liquid unequaled short gaudy ticket imaginary engine positiontent productive plough year uncovered adorable subtract quarrelsome whole dust rare aquatic snow defeated"
words_list = words.split() 
ran = random.choice(words_list)
ln = len(ran)
tries = 0
letters_guesed = []
correct_letter = []
ran_word = list(ran)
astr = list('_' * ln)
new = "".join(correct_letter)
lt = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

x = True
while x == True:
    print(ran)
    astr_str = ''.join(astr)
    print("\n hears what you have so far", astr)
    print("Here are the letters you have guessed so far:",letters_guesed)
    person = input(" guess the letter of the word(once all letters are filled hit enter one more time):")
    
if person in lt:
    if person not in letters_guesed:
        if person not in ran_word:
            letters_guesed.append(person)
            tries += 1
            if tries == 5:
                print("you were wrong the right word was:", ran)
                x = False

    elif len(person) > 1:
        print("\nplease input one letter at a time")

    else:
        print(person,"is aready guessed")

else:
    print("\nnot a valid guess")
    
# needs to be fixed 38 - 48
if person in ran_word:
    if person not in correct_letter:
        ran_l = ran_word.count(person)
        if person in ran_word:
            index = ran_word.index(person)
            correct_letter.insert(index, person)
        for item in range(ran_l):
            if person in ran_word:
                index = ran_word.index(person)
                astr.insert(index, person)
                astr.pop(index)
    print(index)

if ran == astr_str:
    x = False
    print("you are right the word was:", ran)


astr.pop(index) removes the element you just inserted on the previous line. If you want to remove the element you're replacing, it needs to be index+1. But to replace an element you can just assign to the index: astr[index] = person

If you're just having trouble removing from a list, most of this code is unnecessary. Please trim it down to a [mre].

Your question never really explains what problem you're having. list.pop(index) is definitely how you remove the item at that index.
